# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Web\www\football\admin\players.php on line 460

Tags: php

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in D:\Web\www\football\admin\players.php on line 460

```
    $query = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT
        team_season_names.SeasonName AS season_name,
        team_seasons.SeasonID AS season_id
        FROM team_season_names,team_seasons
        WHERE team_seasons.SeasonID = team_season_names.SeasonID
        AND team_seasons.SeasonPlayerID = '$player_id'
        ORDER BY season_name
    ") or die(mysqli_error());
    $all_seasons = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT SeasonID FROM team_season_names") or die(mysqli_error());
    $check_player = mysqli_num_rows($all_seasons);
    mysqli_free_result($all_seasons);

    $check_players = mysqli_num_rows($query);
    $check_seasons = "";
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo "".$data['season_name']."<br>\n";
        $check_season[] = $data['season_id'];
        $check_seasons .= "<option value='".$data['season_id']."'>".$data['season_name']."</option>\n";
    }
    if ($check_player != $check_players) {
        $i = 0;
        echo "<br>Copy this Player to Season: <select name='copy_season'>";
        $get_seasons = mysqli_query($db_connect, "SELECT * FROM team_season_names ORDER BY SeasonName") or die(mysqli_error());
        while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($get_seasons)) {
            if ($data['SeasonID'] != $check_season[$i]) { // Line 460
                echo "<option value='".$data['SeasonID']."'>".$data['SeasonName']."</option>\n";
            } else {
                $i++;
            }
        }
        mysqli_free_result($get_seasons);

        echo "</select>\n";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='copy_season_submit' value='Copy'><br><br>\n";
        echo "You may Remove Player from Season: <select name='remove_season'>".$check_seasons."</select>\n";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='remove_season_submit' value='Remove'>\n";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='player_id' value='".$player_id."'>\n";
        echo "</form>\n";
    } else if ($check_player == $check_players) {
        echo "You may Remove Player from Season: <select name='remove_season'>".$check_seasons."</select>\n";
        echo "<input type='submit' name='remove_season_submit' value='Remove'>\n";
        echo "<input type='hidden' name='player_id' value='".$player_id."'>\n";
        echo "</form>\n";
    }
    mysqli_free_result($query);
```

I all ready use isset() and empty() and they got the error off but then it shows me all seasons for the player and I only want to get the seasons that the player it's not all ready in and another thing it only shows me this error when I only have one season select for the player and it's the first season example 2015/16

Comment: You could do an `empty` or `isset` check on `$check_season[$i]` before using it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable" and "Notice: Undefined index"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index)

Comment: try that all ready and it got the error off but then it shows me all seasons for the player and I only want to get the seasons that the player it's not all ready in

Comment: What did you use? Update the question.

Comment: If you want to limit the results use a `where` clause.

Comment: how show me a example please